# Require.js JST files

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

This is my sample JST file

```
(function() {
  var _ref;

  if ((_ref = window.JST) == null) {
    window.JST = {};
  }

 window.JST['test'] = function(context) {
   return (function() {
   var $o;

  $o = [];
  $o.push("<h1>yayyyyyyaa</h1>");
  return $o.join("\n");
 }).call(context);
};

}).call(this);
```

I use require.js in a backbone app, like

```
define ['backbone', 'marionette', 'text!javascripts/backbone/templates/test.jst'],    
(Backbone, Marionette, template) ->

   class Test extends Backbone.Marionette.ItemView
       template: JST[template]
```

And when i load the app, i get:

```
ReferenceError: JST is not defined
```

Why oh why!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are getting the text of the function in your "template" variable. You still need to `eval` that text to create an actual JST instance on the window.

The problem as a whole is that you are abusing the text! plugin, what you really need to do is  use the modules of requireJs instead of hanging your variables on the window.